# Fail to identify correct alternative from objective question

Tags: r

My question is related to R.
I have code snippet related to 5 answer choice. When I run this answer  choice every choice except one get error. The right one also did not match with the question.

My question is

```
   A  B  C  D  E
1  7  4 23 68 15
2 12 53 14 10 20
3 39 88 98 50 84
4 18 38 33 47 72
5 31  6 51 38 27
6 20 15 68 99 50
```

This dataframe is given. To create this data frame I write the following code block.

```
A = c(7,12,39,18,31,20)
B = c(4,53,88,38,6,15)
C = c(23,14,98,33,51,68)
D = c(68,10,50,47,38,99)
E = c(15,20,84,72,27,50)
df_x = data.frame(A,B,C,D,E)
```

Question: **Which of the following R code will sunset data frame df_x,returning the final three rows?**

My answer choice is

1. `df_x[nrow(df_x)-2:nrow(df_x)]`
2. `df_x[(nrow(df_x)-2):nrow(df_x)]`
3. `df_x[nrow(df-x)-2:,]`
4. `df_x[-3:]`
5. `df_x[(nrow(df_x)-2):nrow(df_x)`

Among them only the 1st choice **df_x[nrow(df_x)-2:nrow(df_x)]** some output.

Output:

```
  D  C  B  A
1 68 23  4  7
2 10 14 53 12
3 50 98 88 39
4 47 33 38 18
5 38 51  6 31
6 99 68 15 20
```

I think this is not the correct one. All other choices give error. Can any one tell me which one is the correct choice? Or what is the actual query to answer the following question? I am new to R. So it is hard for me to find out the correct one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem you are being expected to recognize (but have not)  is operator precedence. The colon operator (for sequencing) has a higher precedence than the binary minus operator, so the expression: nrow(df_x)-2:nrow(df_x) gives you the vector difference possibly with recycling of the value of nrow(df_x) and the vector 2:nrow(df_x). So option number 2 which isolates `nrow(df_x)-2` from the colon-operator with parentheses will give you the correct index. Adding parentheses to make terms obvious is good programming practice. See:

```
?Syntax
```

The other problem is that there is a missing comma after those expressions ... I think your course text should have given option 2 as

```
 df_x[(nrow(df_x)-2):nrow(df_x),]
```

Answer (score 1):

df_x[(nrow(df_x)-2):nrow(df_x),]

Keep in mind, convention is df[rows, columns]. And you need to specify both arguments, which is why I put a comma after the row argument in the solution

Cheers,
Joe

Answer (score 1):

The answers in those choices will produce errors because they are not creating the indexes properly.

In R, when you are subsetting  database, you need to give the row numbers and the column numbers.

For example,`df[row,col]` will give you the data that is the given row and the given column. `df[row,]` will select all columns for the given row number.

If you don't put a comma (,) in the index, you are only selecting the columns. For e.g`df[1:2]` is going to select the first and second columns

If you want to select multiple rows or multiple columns, you can put the numbers in as well e.g `df[1:3,3:9]`

When you use -, R removes the given row or column. So for example, `df[-1,]` removes the first row. `df[,-3]` removes the third column. `df[-1:-5,]` removes the first five rows.

Those answers all have errors in them because they don't have commas in the right places. If you want to select up to the last row or column in R, you need to give the last row or column number. You get this number by using `nrow(df)` or `ncol(df)`. Using the `:` is the Python way of doing things.

The closest answer here is: `df_x[(nrow(df_x)-2):nrow(df_x)]`  but you need to add a comma: `df_x[(nrow(df_x)-2):nrow(df_x),]`

Comment: Thank you so much. It is really good explanation and very helpful for beginners like me.